# Do backhand pushups ever make sense? Do martial artists even condition the backs of their hands?

Tags: conditioning

Do backhand pushups ever make sense? Is it practiced in any martial arts?

I recall I did them once (where I got that idea, I don't remember). I couldn't even lean on the backs of my hands at first, but then I learned to do a substantial amount of pushups in that position and gave it up (it simply became a tricep exercise, and I worked on my triceps separately). But now I'm wondering, where does it come from, what was it designed for? One of my guesses is that it has something to do with martial arts, specifically hand conditioning. On the other hand, you don't punch with the back of your hand, for all I know (even in reverse punches, you employ knuckles). If the exercise is actually useful, I could theoretically make it harder and resume

[image]

Comment: Also, multiple perspectives at https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/comments/873h9i/why_wrist_push_ups_are_not_as_beneficial_as_you/

Answer (score 3):

I have never actually performed them as part of a martial art, but in other forms of exercise that I have done, the emphasis has been on building up strength and flexibility in the wrist in all directions. By learning to push back in that direction for support, you decrease the likelihood of spraining your wrist on a punch, or while catching yourself in a fall.